# Identical duplicate notifications in TFS 2013

Tags: tfs, notifications, tfsbuild

I have a team project with one team defined, which consists of a domain groups and individual members. Some domains group have users which are individual members of the team project.

I created build alerts with Subscriber `{the team project name}`

The team is getting two or three identical alerts each time a monitored event is triggered. I understand why this happened! Because the team includes members and domain groups which have those members. I know I can set Subscriber to just user. But it's not a work around.

Does anyone know how to resolve this problem?

I mean, I want set up subscriber `{the team project name}` and each member this project team received one message. Regardless of how many times they are found in a group.

Comment: We've also had this problem ([along with others](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1288aed8-844f-41ba-a1de-a9fc3ab8cfd6/getting-multiple-emails-from-alerts-in-tfs-2012?forum=tfsgeneral)) and it appears that [MS closed the ticket on Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/765694/duplicate-project-notification-emails-received-when-an-active-directory-group-is-added-as-a-tfs-team-member).  I'm afraid there is no work around.

Comment: Right... We ended up recommending our users to use individual subscriptions...

Comment: Are your AD groups also distribution lists? If you use an AD groups that is not also a distribution list do you get the a same issue?

Comment: Correct, they are also distribution lists.

Comment: You can also try to [monitor changes of TFS work items using a CatLight notifier](https://catlight.io/a/tfs-work-item-notifications). Compared to email alerts, it will notify people continuously until they acknowledge the change, and it  does not have a problem with giving a lot of outdated notification to developers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design if your AD groups are also distribution lists. TFS is, correctly, sending an alert to the distribution list.

The only way around this is to:

- Use AD Groups that are not also distribution lists
- Add users explicitly to the TFS Group (this is recommended for Teams)

Comment: Interesting... Can you please elaborate more about why it is by design? Does TFS iterate the AD group tree and send a notification to any distribution list it meets? Thanks for your answer!

Comment: That is my belief and that would be as I would expect. If you add a email enabled group to TFS it will email that group when in scope. If you also have a user from that group added then I would expect that user to also get an email.

Comment: I have verified that and it DOES send duplicates in case an AD group is also a distribution list. Hence, multiple group membership results in multiple notifications sent to the end user... Anyway, thanks for your answer